# how to print the following information out without getting this warning?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
#define HELLO
"this is a command to ........." //this macros is very long, and it is greater than length 509
```

then I use `printf(HELLO);` to print it out, but I got the following warning:

warning: string length '526' is greater than the length '509' ISO C90 compilers are required to support, I know the string is too long, it is greater than 509, but how to remove this warning?

Comment: Shorten the string...

Comment: You forgot the format specifier.

Comment: yes, but it is the same warning

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Take a look at [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) break it into 2 strings 
    #define a "abc"
    #define b "def"
    #define c (a b)
now both `printf(a b)` or `printf(c)` would work

2) just suppress the warning, (code is working, is not it?? :)) (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

3) ohh just now saw 3rd option, use different standard

1st one is not useful, it will not solve the problem

Comment: I doubt that the first trick is going to work, because the standard limits the number of characters in a literal *after* concatenation. The `"abc"` and `"def"` would be under the limit, but the pasted literal `"abc""def"` would go over the limit. The second option looks fine, though, and so does the third.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks for pointing out, 1st option is not useful, preprocessing itself will concat the strings and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a C99-compliant compiler if possible, the limit in C99 is 4,095 characters.

Failing that, build the string at run-time (once) into a global character array.